# Making users tap on ads on Android - legal or not?

Tags: android, admob, ads, google-play

In free app, I'd like to hide ads forever after some number of clicks on banner. And users will know about this rule.
In my opinion, if user made some money for developer, let's let him be free from ads. But all systems of ads are checking for cheating to avoid auto-clicks or something like that. So, what can you tell about major ads platforms on Google Play (Google ads, AdMob, etc.) - is it possible to do such thing or it will be judged like cheating then many users will become to do many clicks one after another to remove ads? Is simple in-app like "Remove ads" better?

Comment: Better to use an in-app purchase to remove ads for something like this. I'd uninstall an app if it wanted me to click its ads.

Comment: Well making users tap on ads is purely illegal according terms of service. Your ad account may be deactivated if u encourage users to click on ad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is against the terms and conditions of every ad network that I am aware of. It could also get you banned on Google Play.

It would be best to use [in app purchases](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html) for this. It will not get you banned on any of the ad networks or Google Play, and is reasonably easy to integrate.